# vb.net bindingsource filter cast date to string

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, casting, filtering, bindingsource

I'm using the [filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx) method of [Binding source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) in VB.net to filter results in a DataGridView based on the text in a search box.  However, the idea of this search, is that it shows a row if *any* of the cells contain the text.  So my filter string ends up looking like this:

```
filter = "ProductId LIKE '%" & searchterm & "%'" & " OR ScanDate like '%" & searchterm & "%'"
```

However, when I try to put the filter in the filter property, it complains, saying that it cannot convert the date column to text for the comparison.

Is there a way to tell the filter to cast the datetime cells to string?

What I'm considering doing is having a hidden column in the dataset that contains a casted version of the date, and I'll tell the filter to filter *that* column.

Here's my assign code:

```
bindingSource.Filter = filter 
dgv.DataSource = bindingSource.DataSource
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it, and it *works*

```
bindingSource.Filter = "ProductId LIKE '%" & searchterm & "%' OR Convert( ScanDate, 'System.String') LIKE '%" & searchterm & "%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should break down your filter code.  So, rather than setting your filter code all in one line, I would run a test on the `searchterm` to see if it is a valid `DateTime`.  Then, you can change your filter accordingly because I don't think you'll have a `ProductId` which is like a `DateTime`.

```
try
{
    string dt = DateTime.Parse(searchterm).ToString();
    filter = "ScanDate like '%" & searchterm & "%'"
}
catch
{
    filter = "ProductId LIKE '%" & searchterm & "%'"
}
```

Sorry for the C# code, but it should be straight forward to convert to VB.Net.

Comment: no problem with it being c#, and this is practical, however, it filters per keystroke, and a productid looks like this PRD1234567, so if they enter "23" it can show any product ids with a 23 in it, or a scan date such as the 23rd of a month: "23/01/2010 12:00:00"

Comment: If they enter 23, it will look at the 23rd hour, the 23rd minute and the 23rd second as well, not just a day search.  You will need to pad out the DateTime in order for it to be a valid date format in order for this to work.  Searching 23 against a format that should be DD/MM/YYYY hh:MM:SS won't work.

Comment: That's what I want it to do.  Entering just a 23 on it's own will return any rows where the productid has a 23, or any aspect of the datetime has a 23 in it, such as "23/01/2010 12:00:00" or "10/01/2023 12:00:00", or "10/01/2010 12:23:00".  It will work exactly as expected if I can cast the column to a string in the filter itself.  Which I don't know how to do.