# Windows Form Filter Int value in DataGridView

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, filter, datagridviewcolumn

When filtering an Integer value in my SQL Server database using the following statement it works:

[image]

Yet, when I filter it within the vb.net code it flags an error:

```
 Dim bs As New BindingSource()
 bs.DataSource = dgvUserList.DataSource
 bs.Filter = dgvUserList.Columns(3).DataPropertyName.ToString() + " LIKE '" + TextBox3.Text + "%'"

 dgvUserList.DataSource = bs
```

**ERROR at bs.Filter line:**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int64 and System.String.
```

I've used this same Filter code on a string value but this is the first time on an integer value. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you use LIKE in that situation at all?  If the user wants to filter to Manny (Id == 1), are they going to want to see users with the ids of 11, 21, 311, 110 - 119?

Comment: yes i need all those scenerios... which would involve a like @Plutonix

Comment: So by using `'12%'` I get an integer with those starting values which is more what I want

Comment: use Convert like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390152/vb-net-bindingsource-filter-cast-date-to-string

Comment: @Crowcoder that worked :) `bs.Filter = "Convert(" + dgvUserList.Columns(3).DataPropertyName.ToString() + ", 'System.String') Like '" + TextBox3.Text + "%'"` Thank you!

Comment: No - just no. Start over. I can't imagine a valid reason to search numbers in this manner - especially for a column of IDs. In addition, you have made a very important logic mistake that is no visible with your limited test data. Searching a list of numbers that begin with a specific digit (like '2') will include the values  ('2', '21', '29', '254', '2000', '20010201', etc.). Searching numeric values for a particular range is done using "between" logic.